# After passing by reference to modify an array, why it stays the same?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, stack, dynamic-arrays

I am practicing pointers by creating a Big Number struct, which has numDigits (number of digits) and digits (contents of the big number).

I create a function called removeZero(). After passing the integer array and the size n into it, because of passing by reference, I am supposed to cut down the leading zeros for my input. It works, when the integer array is in main function. However, when I pass an array that is in readDigits, it does not return with a non-leading-zero version. Why? How to fix it?

```
struct BigNum{
    int numDigits;
    int *digits;  //the content of the big num
};

int main(){
    int A[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3};
    int n=9;
    int *B=A;
    //removeZero(A,n); If I use this, it cannot compile
    //error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int*&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int*’

    removeZero(B,n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    std::cout << *(B+i) << std::endl;
    }

    BigNum *num = readDigits();

    return 0;
}

BigNum* readDigits(){  
    std::string digits;
    std::cout << "Input a big number:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> digits; 

    //resultPt in heap or in stack?
    int *resultPt = new int[digits.length()]; //in heap
    int n = digits.length();
    toInt(digits,resultPt);
    removeZero(resultPt,n);

    //Output the leading zeros, why?
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    std::cout << *(resultPt +i) << std::endl;
    }

    BigNum *numPtr = new BigNum();
    numPtr->numDigits = n;
    numPtr->digits = resultPt;

    return numPtr;
}

void toInt(std::string& str, int *result){
    for (int i=0;i<str.length() ;i++ ){
    result[str.length()-i-1] = (int)(str[i]-'0');
    }
}

void removeZero(int* &A,int& n){
    int i=0;
    while (A[i]==0){
    i++;
    }
    A=A+i; //memory leak?
    n=n-i;
}

bool areDigits(std::string num){
    for(int i=0;i<num.length();i++){
    if(num[i]<'0' || num[i] >'9'){
        return false;
     }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `//removeZero(A,n); Why I cannot compile without pointer B?` What error does this give?

Comment: where is `removeZero()`?

Comment: Provide your implementtaion of void removeZero(int *a, int m);

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: Implementation of removeZero is provided now.

Comment: @DebasishJana: Implementation of removeZero is provided now.

Comment: `A=A+i; //memory leak?` This is definitely a memory leak when `A` is originally allocated with `new`.

Comment: Rather than physically removing the zeros from the array representation of your `BigNumber`, can you simply ignore them when you print out the value?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: No, I cannot. It's required by specification. The only way that I can do is to remove the zeros from the int array, but it seems that I cannot. It's a university assignment, so I don't know the other implementations.

Comment: What are the **exact** specifications?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: I will use this BigNum to do arithmetic calculation. The result of addition, subtraction, multiplication should not have leading zeros. Therefore, I was wondering to create a removeZero() to remove the zeros after any arithmetic calculations.

Comment: You are still paraphrasing the specifications. Please provide the **exact** description for the `removeZero()` function.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: Sorry for the confusion. The removeZero is not required in the specification. The "real" specification is:"Use this BigNum to do arithmetic calculation. The result of addition, subtraction, multiplication should not have leading zeros. "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63655/discussion-between-fan-and-code-apprentice).

Comment: You should use `std::vector` and not C-style arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that an array and a pointer are two different things. When you pass an array to a function, it degrades to a `const` pointer. This means that you cannot pass an array to a function which expects a `int*&`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. So after passing by reference to modify an array, why it stays the same?

Comment: @Fan What stays the same? The original array? Because you cannot modify an array to have a new starting location. On the other hand, you **can** modify the pointer `B` to point to a new location. This doesn't modify the array `A` to which `B` originally pointed.

Comment: int *resultPt = new int[digits.length()]; Even the array is created by new, I still cannot modify the starting point?

Comment: @Fan Yes, you can, but that causes a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the problem of scope of numPtr.numPtr is local variable of function readDigits(). Instead of returning pointer. Pass num to readDigits().

Comment: numPtr is local, but the content of numPtr is returned, which is the address of BigNum.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of your removeZero function is:

```
void removeZero(int* &A,int& n);
```

That means the forst parameter is a reference of a pointer but the pointer is a non-const one, and you cannot therefore pass an array there, as array is a constant pointer (starting address cannot be changed).
In fact you are changing the starting address within removeZero.
With removeZero, the while loop shopuld be changed from:

```
while (A[i]==0){
```

to:

```
while ((A[i]==0) && (i<n)){
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic error in `toInt`.

```
void toInt(std::string& str, int *result){
    for (int i=0;i<str.length() ;i++ ){

    // This stores the digits in the reverse order.
    result[str.length()-i-1] = (int)(str[i]-'0');
    }
}
```

That line should be

```
    result[i] = (int)(str[i]-'0');
```

If you intend to keep the digits in reverse order, then `removeZero` has to be changed keeping that in mind.
`

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
int *B=A;
```

you are just creating a pointer to point to the same memory
of the Array A. Just by incrementing the pointer(*B) within the function
removeZero

```
A=A+i;
```

you are not deleting anything but you are just incrementing the pointer(*B)
to point to subsequent memory location within the array.
The original array memory pointed to by A remains the same, since you
have not changed any contents of the array, but you have just
incremented a pointer pointing to the same memory location as that of the array.

Also there are so many problems, like "Debasish Jana" mentioned,
you have to change your while loop. ""Code-Apprentice" gave you the reason for your
compilation error when you uncomment your commented code.
Also within "removeZero" you are incrementing A by i instead of "1" like

```
A=A+1;
```

This is one of the reason for the strange behavior you experience

Even after changing all this, you cannot see your array getting changed,
since you are not modifying any of the contents of your array.

If you really want to delete the contents of the array and change it dynamically,
you have to go for Vector<>. With static memory allocation you cannot cut the 
array size short by removing some elements here and there. Learn Vector<>!